# .NET Core Opening Linux FIFO (named) pipe blocks execution

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, named-pipes, .net-standard

I have a legacy *C++* application to test from a *.NET Core* application. The *C++* code uses *Linux FIFO* pipes to communicate with other processes. I managed to successfully communicate with the software under test (SUT) by creating the FIFO file and opening it like this:
`File.Open(Path.Combine(this.PipePath, this.PipeName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Write)`
My problem is that for some reason, this line blocks execution until the pipe is opened by the SUT on the other side. I create Tasks to open and receive data from these pipes, but I have to be able detect with a timeout if a pipe is not opened, interrupt the task and print an error.
Currently I don't know how to achieve this, as the Tasks just hang there, synchronously waiting for the pipe to be opened. The library that contains this code is a *.NET Standard 2.0* library.

Comment: Have you tried out anything, yet or are you completely hitting a wall, there?

Comment: I currently hit a wall. I need way either to find a way to open the file which is interruptible (i.e.: with cancellation token) or to interrupt a Task which is stuck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't got a linux system at hand to try it out, so I won't be able to write up an answer nor even try any ideas. I would suggest you create a separate set of projects as an "experimentation lab" to reduce complexity during the process of finding a solution.